# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: asp.net

In my web application,i am storing password in the database using encryption. the password field's datatype is nvarchar(max). Even i enter the 10 character password e.g. '8427484274' then also i am getting the error. I came to know by searching this is the error we get when we try to store the data more then the datatype's capacity..one thing i want to make clear is that i have '=' symbol in my encrypted string...is there any issue with datatype?if so what can be the biggest datatype then varchar(8000),i have tried that also and still getting the error.how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try varchar(max)... means more then 8000...so it should be good...maybe you passing values to a stored procedure & its parameter length is invalid.

Comment: i tried varchar(max) also...i am not using any sp etc...simply calling encrypt(8427484274) and then storing returned value in database...the reason why i am confused is that i am using biggest available datatype and then also the error...?

Comment: did you try to copy the query and executed within SQL Management Studio?

Comment: paste your code...and are you sure your encrypt functions returns a STRING (no binary data).

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into emp_details VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + strpassword + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "',null,'" + Session["tem"].ToString() + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: encrypt function:private string Encryptdata(string password)
        {
            string strmsg = string.Empty;
            byte[] encode = new byte[password.Length];
            encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            strmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(encode);
            return strmsg;
        }

Comment: strpassword calls the Encrypt function? i am starting to think problem is with different column not the password column. can you double check the length of all columns?

Comment: or try to INSERT password ONLY and see what happens...paste your encrypted INSERT statement here.

Comment: so silly of me,there was a minor error in my query that affects the different column then the password...it was modified by mistake....now its working fine....thanks for your quick support....my 5..!

Answer (score 0):

Suspect that the problem would in passing the values from the application. Check the datatype and length of command parameter.

Comment: i already clarified that i have tried all the datatype...forget about ALL,it gives error with varchar(max) also..my question is WHY THIS IS SO? it should not give me error with the biggest datatype available...uh...!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have a quote in the data? It will cause bad things to happen. I usually do a   string.Replace('''', '''''') which converts a single quote to a double quote.

Try running it again in the debugger and see what the value of cmd.commandtext is. Put it in a response here so we can see what is actually being run.

Comment: thanks for your kind support....the error had been resolved....the problem was with another column name and datatype...